# I don't want to convert solution files when switching from Visual Studio 2008-2010. How?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I just got a new work laptop. I want to run Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2. However, the rest of my team is using Visual Studio 2008 with .Net 3.5, and I don't want to check-in the solution migration code into TFS. In fact, I don't want any migration code at all - I just want to use the old .NET Framework with our old solution, with the new IDE. How can I do this? Is this possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

The entire migration is one line changing in the solution file, and it can't be avoided. Only the solution file is changed though - not the project file - so I suggest doing the 'standard' thing and copying your `Solution.sln` file into `Solution2010.sln` and migrating that. One thing you have to notice is that if the solution file is updated, by adding or removing projects, you must keep the two files in sync.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you cannot . It was the files that your project references...

http://blogs.msdn.com/visualstudio/archive/2010/03/15/why-does-visual-studio-2010-convert-my-projects.aspx